# $S \subset X$ maximal discrete subset of $X$ and $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous surjective map. Show $f(S) \cap (0,1) \neq \emptyset$.

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space and define $Y \subset X$ to be discrete if the subspace topology on $Y$ is the discrete topology.  Let $S \subset X$ be the maximal discrete subset of $X$ and let $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous surjective map.  Prove $f(S) \cap (0,1) \neq \emptyset$.

My attempt: I want to show $S \cap f^{-1}(0,1) \neq \emptyset$.  Since $f$ continuous $f^{-1}(0,1)$ open in $X$ and not empty since $f$ is surjective.  Then it follows that $S \cap f^{-1}(0,1)$ open in $S$ by the subspace topology. Not sure how to finish off - my only idea would be to somehow use the fact that $S$ is maximal, so if $S \cap f^{-1}(0,1) = \emptyset$ to create a larger discrete set than $S$ to get a contradiction.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $U$ be non-empty open in $\Bbb R$. If $f[S]$ misses $U$, then $f^{-1}[U]$ misses $S$. Pick $p$ in it and also pick open $V$ in $\Bbb R$ such that $f(p) \in V$ and $\overline{V} \subseteq U$. (Using $\Bbb R$ is regular for a technical reason..)

Then $T:=S \cup \{p\}$ is discrete: $s \in S$ is open in $S$, so $U_s \subseteq X$ open exists with $U_s \cap S = \{s\}$. Now $U'_s:=U_s\setminus f^{-1}[\overline{V}]$ is open (open minus closed) and $U'_s \cap T = \{s\}$. So $\{s\}$ is still open in $T$. And $\{p\}$ is open as it equals $f^{-1}[U] \cap T$ by construction.

$T$ contradicts the maximality of $S$, so $f[S]$ must intersect every non-empty open subset of $\Bbb R$; i.e. its dense in it; we could show similarly that $S$ is dense in $X$ if $X$ were assumed to be $T_1$; the $V$ above is to circumvent this potential nuisance.

Comment: Ingenious trick thanks for clarifying this.

Answer (score 2):

To create a larger discrete subset, just take $x\in X\setminus S$ such that $f(x)\in(0,1)$.  Then $S\cup\{x\}$ is discrete, since $x\in f^{-1}(0,1)$, and $f^{-1}(0,1)$ is open and disjoint from $S$.  That is, $\{x\}$ is clopen in $S\cup\{x\}$.

Comment: How does showing $\{x\}$ clopen in $S \cup \{x\}$ prove that $S \cup \{x\}$ is discrete?  I was able to see that $\{x\}$ is open in $S \cup \{x\}$ but how is it closed ie. how do I show $S$ is open in $S \cup \{x\}$?

Comment: $S$ is discrete, so its points are open.  So $S$ is the union of open sets, hence open.  Thus $\{x\}$ is closed,

Comment: From what I understood, $S$ being discrete implies its points are open in $S$ - so for all $s \in S$ there exists and open $U_{s}$ in $X$ such that $\{s\} = U_{s} \cap S$.  How does this ensure that $s$ is open in $S \cup \{x\}$, since using the same $U_{s}$ does not ensure that $\{s\} = U_{s} \cap (S \cup \{x\})$ (since it might be that $U_{s} \cap \{x\} \neq \emptyset$).  This is the technicality I'm stuck on.

Comment: @SaranWrap see my answer how to avoid this issue.

Comment: As @HennoBrandsma points out, $X$ being $T_1$ would solve this.  But there is no such assumption.  I guess we have to look to Henno to bail us out.

Comment: @ChrisCuster appreciate the help very much thank you